# dynamically rezising a 2D array in C

Tags: c

I have a function a 2D array:
`size_t **trips;`
and I have a function to resize it by one line each time the function is called (and fills with 0´s the new spaces). However it generates segmentation fault.

```c
static void enlargeTrips(size_t **trips, size_t dim)
{
    errno = 0;
    int i, j;
    trips = realloc(trips, dim * sizeof(size_t *));
    if (errno == ENOMEM)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    { // lleno de 0 la nueva fila
        trips[dim - 1][j] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        trips[i] = realloc(trips[i], sizeof(size_t) * dim); 
        if (errno == ENOMEM){
            return ;
        }
        trips[i][dim - 1] = 0; 
    }
}
```

How can I improve this? or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: You never allocate new memory for the new rows.

Comment: @manuCT, A failed allocation does not certainly set `errno == ENOMEM`.  Testing if the return value is `NULL` is more portable (when `dim != 0`).

Comment: Look at `realloc`. It returns a value. Do you know why it needs to? Now look at your function. It does not return a value, even though it's essentially a 2D realloc. Can you explain to your nearest rubber duck which law of physics lets your function get away with it?

Comment: I imagine this probably costs a lot of computation; the memory is probably going to be allocated fairly poorly for repeatedly adding one to a row. However, is there a better way to do what? What are you doing?

Comment: "I have a function a 2D array: `size_t **trips;`" -- No, no, you don't. `size_t **` has nothing to do with an array. It is a collection of pointers each of which get assigned the address for an allocated block of memory. You can *index* like you would a 2D array, but a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `type` is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a potential memory leak as you do not save the pointer before reallock.
2. You need to have a new value off trips known to the caller. You can return it or use a reference.
3. Your array is not 2d array only an array of pointers.
4. To correctly manage the deallocations if resize fails I would suggest not using `realloc` in this case
5. In your code you do not indicate an error condition.

```
size_t **enlargeTrips(size_t **trips, const size_t dim, size_t old_dim)
{
    size_t **newTrips = calloc(dim, sizeof(*newTrips));

    if(!newTrips) goto errorExit;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < dim; index++)
    {
        if(!(newTrips[index] = malloc(dim *sizeof(**trips)))) goto errorExit;
        if(index < old_dim)
        {
            memcpy(newTrips[index], trips[index], old_dim *sizeof(**trips));
            memset(newTrips[index] + old_dim, 0, (dim - old_dim) *sizeof(**trips));
        }
        else
        {
            memset(newTrips[index], 0, dim *sizeof(**trips));
        }
    }

    //all good free old array
    for(size_t index = 0; index < dim; index++)
    {
        free(trips[index]);
    }
    free(trips);
    return newTrips;

    errorExit:
    if(newTrips)
        for(size_t index = 0; index < dim; index++)
        {
            free(newTrips[index]);
        }
    free(newTrips);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `realloc` resizes the array of pointers, but it does not set the newly added pointer element. It is not set to 0 automatically. So when you access `trips[dim - 1]` in the first loop, its value is undefined (could be garbage). Then the result of dereferencing it with offset `j` is also undefined. You have not allocated the memory yet that you try to access there. Later on, in the second loop you reallocate the "inner" arrays of size_t values, but since the new pointer has not been set, you are supplying an undefined value to `realloc` in the first argument, which also results in undefined behavior (if it doesn't randomly happen to be 0 or the address of something that has previously been allocated by `malloc` or `realloc`).

You need to allocate memory for the new size_t array before you can set its elements to 0. If you wanted to exploit the fact that `realloc` can also allocate completely new blocks of memory (like `malloc`), you need to ensure that the new pointer is initially 0.

Moreover, the first realloc can return a new memory address for the pointer array, but you don't communicate it back to the caller of the function. (The trips argument is a copy of the pointer that the caller supplied.) So after the call, the caller will most likely still have the old pointer value of trips, which can lead to undefined behavior if the array memory was moved by realloc and you try to access the data through the old pointer later. You should return the new `trips` pointer.